# jQuery $(this).css('border-color') returns old border color

Tags: jquery

Why does the following code return the previously updated border color and not the current border color ?

**Html:**

```
<li><a href="#" data-target="#signupModal" data-toggle="modal" id="signup">
<i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Sign Up </a></li>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#signup').click(function() {

  var count = 0;

  $('#inputEmail').focusout(function() {

    if ($(this).val() == '') {

      count++;
      $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
      console.log('No of times input box focused out: ' + count + ' Current border color: ' + $(this).css('border-color'));
    } else {

      $(this).css('border-color', 'green');
      console.log(' Current border color: ' + $(this).css('border-color'));
    }
  });
});
```

It changes border color perfectly fine but it does not display the currently updated border color in the browser console rather it display the previously updated border color.

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine [JsFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jsn2248h/)

Comment: @user3284463 it does change the border color perfectly but in browser console it return old border color

Comment: Really bad practice creating event handlers inside other event handlers when you are uncertain about the implications of doing so. Explain your higher level objective here

Comment: @charlietfl Its displaying old border color rather than current border color

Comment: That doesn't explain the higher level objective such as why user needs to click on button first or what purpose of changing borders is

Comment: okay i am trying to change the border color to red if user typed invalid input and if he/she typed valid input then it should change to green color. later in the program i need to check the current border color and accordingly execute some set of statement if its red otherwise it should execute other set of statements if its green. so for that i need to get the current border color.

Comment: @charlietfl and can you please tell me why its bad practice to create event handlers inside other event handler ? and what is the good practice. btw thanks alot for the reply :)

Comment: Because if user clicks button more than once another event listener will be added ... lcik agian a third listener is added and so on. There appears to be no reason the button needs to be clicked in order to add the listener to the input

Comment: I wouldn't derive validation state by checking a css property, add/remove a class and then later use `$.hasClass('has-errors')` or whatever to test.

Comment: @charlietfl how would i fix the problem and what would be better approach in my example ???

Comment: @JaredFarrish thanks for the reply. why not check with css property ?? any specific reason ??

Comment: Current issue is probably due to browser needing a chance to repaint with the new color before it gets queried to get that color back from the dom. What browser are you using?

Comment: chrome it happens with every browser

Comment: Move the focus listener outside the click handler. May not solve issue but it does not belong inside

Comment: ... and make `count` an outer var of both handlers.

Comment: Because you don't store validation in css properties, those properties are for describing display state.

Comment: Something very odd is happening because two consecutive statements, one that writes and one that reads a CSS property, should be 100% reliable. After the first statement, the DOM should be guaranteed to be mutated even if the screen has not been repainted.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Thanks alot ☺️ and yes its very odd that its not returning the current border color instead it returns the old border color.

Comment: @charlietfl what if i do something like this: `function abc ()  { $('#inputEmail'). focusout ( function () { ... } ); }` and call that function like this: `$('#signup').click(function() { ... abc (); .... }` ?? would that still be bad practice ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is causing this bug. However, more cleaner approach would be to define a `color` variable and log that variable color instead:

```
var count = 0 ;

$('#inputEmail').focusout ( function(){
   var color = "";

   if ( $(this).val() == '' ){
      count++;

      color = "red"; /* Update variable */
      $(this).css('border-color',color);

      console.log('No of times input box focused out: ' + count + ' Current border color: ' + color);

   } else {

     color = "green"; /* Update variable */
     $(this).css('border-color', color);

     console.log(' Current border color ' + color);
   }
});
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jsn2248h/2/)

Comment: @charlietfl He is tryting to log the `border-color` of an element using `$(this).css(..)` and it doesn't seem to be doing its job. Hmm, this is the solution I could think of

Comment: OK well in the case of using variable suggest only changing variables inside `if()` and only use one log statement and one `.css()` call to DRY it a bit

Comment: @Doda Did you give the above answer a try?

Comment: Now i am not gonna validate input on bases of css as others have suggested but thanks for help anyways :)